# Таймер показывает Nan в браузере Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, таймер

Есть такой скрипт. В браузере сафари показывает Nan

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('body').countdown('10/31/2016 24:00:00')
.on('update.countdown', function(event) {
  $('.years').html(event.strftime('%Y'))
  $('.months').html(event.strftime('%m'))
  $('.weeks').html(event.strftime('%w'))
  $('.days').html(event.strftime('%D'))
  $('.hours').html(event.strftime('%H'))
  $('.minutes').html(event.strftime('%M'))
  $('.seconds').html(event.strftime('%S'));
})
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.studio-073.nl/cwsyn/deadline-expired.html';
});
</script>
```

Скрипт отлично работает в таком случае:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('body').countdown('02/07/2020 11:05:00')
.on('update.countdown', function(event) {
  $('.years').html(event.strftime('%Y'))
  $('.months').html(event.strftime('%m'))
  $('.weeks').html(event.strftime('%w'))
  $('.days').html(event.strftime('%D'))
  $('.hours').html(event.strftime('%H'))
  $('.minutes').html(event.strftime('%M'))
  $('.seconds').html(event.strftime('%S'));
})
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
  window.location.href = 'http://example.com/';
});
</script>
```

Не понимаю в какую сторону копать, прочитал про форматы, изменил. Все равно продолжаются проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').countdown('10/31/2016 24:00:00')
```

Думаю вы задаете в параметр 2016 год, а он как бы закончился)

Попробуйте поставить 2017

Comment: Все правильно. Фишка в том, что год закончился и дальше меня должно было перекинуть. Я тестировал и вроде заработал такой формат: 2016/10/31 00:00:00

Comment: Отредактируйте условие и укажите, что вам нужно, чтобы перекидывало на указанную ссылку, а не то что указанно изначально.
Потому-что думал проблема именно в NaN

Comment: Уточнения добавляются в комментарий. Ваша репутация позволяет уточнить. Код можно записать в ` ` скобки.

Comment: Да перекидывало. Но в сафари на таймере показывает NaN) И в следствии nan не перекидывает. Если поставить время на будущее то таймер работает, но будет ли он срабатывать?